# no matter what you input i always get ID is not in list plz

Tags: python, python-3.x

no matter what you input I always get an ID that is not on the list

```
ID = [45, 33, 27, 88, 103, 66, 71] #list
numberSought = input("Please enter ID number to find:") #input whith an input
found = False
n = len(ID)
k= 0
while  found == False and k < n:
    if numberSought  == ID [k]:
        found = True
    k  += 1#  k += k == k = k + 1
if found == True:
    print("ID is in the list at index", k - 1)
else:
    print("ID is not in the list")
```

Comment: Im guessing that its something to do with the:  if numberSought  == ID [k]:
        found = True

Comment: Hint: Use `print(type(numberSought))`

Comment: And once you have worked out why @KrishnaChaurasia 's comment solves your problem, try using `ID.index(numberSought)` instead of scanning through the list yourself. Are you maybe working from a Python 2 example? The `input()` call you wrote would have worked in Python 2.

Comment: no I'm trying to recreate python questions from my pseudo exam

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way of doing the exact same thing:

```
ID = [45, 33, 27, 88, 103, 66, 71] #list
number = int(input("Please enter ID number to find:")) #input whith an input

if number in ID:
    print(f"ID is in the list at index {ID.index(number)}")
else:
    print("ID is not in the list")
```

Comment: can you make it loop so if the player uses a string it loops so that they can input again and also when they finnished the program it restarts

Comment: Look [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-indefinitely-request-user-input-until-valid-in-python-388a7c85aa6e) for a recipie.